# how to connect to PostgreSQL using Streaming Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am trying to build POC on connecting to PostgreSQL using Streaming Integrator with CDC listening mode. I am new to this WSO2 product-Streaming Integrator and I am not getting any example for reference.

Can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the Debezium[1] documentation to configure the CDC in Postgress DB level, and then read through the Siddhi IO CDC doc[2] in order to create a cdc source in Streaming Integrator side.

[1]https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.4/connectors/postgresql.html#setting-up-postgresql
[2]https://siddhi-io.github.io/siddhi-io-cdc/api/latest/
[3]https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/streaming-integrator/samples/CDCWithListeningMode/